# Jmeter - Getting Response code:403 Response message:Forbidden error

Tags: jmeter

I have created a Jmeter 5.3 script. The login works fine but after that i am getting > Response code:403
Response message:Forbidden error for the subsequent requests.

In the past, it worked when I added X-XSRF-TOKEN to the header manager. Now it is not working even with that. Any input is appreciated.

> Request Body:
> POST https://rrsso.secure.com/cargobkgwar/services/userroles/lookup

> POST data:
> {"ReferenceMenuController":{},"QueueConsoleController":{},"MasterTableListController":{},"MasterTableEditController":{},"SampleUsageController":{},"SampleUserListController":{},"SampleUserEditController":{},"SampleChartController":{},"UpdatePasswordController":{},"UserPropertiesListController":{},"UserPropertiesEditController":{},"AccessDeniedController":{},"SubRulesController":{},"RuleHistoryController":{},"AboutReleaseController":{},"ReleaseNotesController":{},"ConsoleController":{},"BookingController":{},"AvailabilityController":{},"BookListController":{},"ManageOfferController":{},"FlightDetailsController":{}}

> Cookie Data:
> XSRF-TOKEN=KZ7uJQ08xDTWQhu2nsWQ4IzhFOHcStIfAVAPrQKNrzHCtWBmnKiz!-568463951!320078472!1610313174332; OAMRequestContext_rrsso.secure.com_443_4f3161=O1a944lrqSv4egD4G2UQpw==; OAMAuthnCookie_rrsso.secure..com_443=aa0c56de9b268c931dc75b986d223a7e955e3921%7E%2B0M7rZF1h6Jboy7dqRl2h1uo79QylW3InDZDfhF8do%2BKb8eELTLFhztLsMtzY%2F%2BFFkt0tS9o%2FuZ7%2Fb4AxFv4FBWDwoICNgZLjeTVzywXc7VWZ75seHp4GdfSVMjlZ3PR45ywO2BC4SXTO9Ol6REN1RUHl6Uc1oMKx7cubZ8AwLZRWhHobuPPopHSCR8O0Q5%2BJQitbg9dC6QrtjlyE%2FnEcicF6B2U%2BOxHxGGiPzxgWrXeMMX8%2Fw1l28lv8L3q1XMekNTlktebGG7MjOrRg7n7x6kqkJMszhGNv8PvE2UASIFDEsTUS%2BjOegew04dLd0BNYk4kL1TzbuJ3F7%2F3dmvpDim3x%2FwTZ8hoyAhjaPy%2FD1i8Lm654%2BOaZJ%2Bza26t9LO0TGgI9OwabeEn89ybtRW5iA%2FmCvgWDrT8lbGbLJ8fs7x%2FYeJ46AWTiomTP7z0%2FnqtRHm14i8hDAkfzXhwhejk75IozsMMwCyUk6jKhxWj8qZ15%2FKDe%2BV5jWl04k7ErrSwenJYyFKw8dUCG1U5Non%2FwQ%3D%3D; OAMAuthnHintCookie=1; rm-sso-uid=8l5lXRW2YxKfuwHXE4THdltQbd8kifYI; JSESSIONIDBLS=nebuJQ8PrrhKt4HoYXoPlUSqNo1AtRa9EkoybY3WWTutoHP3pAjv!-568463951!320078472; OAM_GITO=GymRbSnLNbhmOaJnOtP9Rw==~9FyIDXwulQBrBv/FQ/0rfKchN2m08TUmNp9ddjOkMzM6p2jM6TRFIX9pTtILuE52BqpRjbHMX9vWA9OXWezYsk9hLj+YvdAvdOcNWDQRwy+szPoGp8Ydt6vfHzK7dFTIgqgNVobqZSe0bH2j0kiXfOI4o2ueWplCBOaX03UxRwNpwAPbtpHU0dbwzjE/UYxu+A/ftlSKBGS/8HmrvwPbBgNnLLprD2Mp1fS8s7InvMM=

> REquest Header:
> Connection: keep-alive
> Referer: https://rrsso.secure.com/cargobkgwar/modules/welcome.html
> Accept-Language: en-US
> DNT: 1
> Pragma: no-cache
> Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; Zoom 3.6.0; wbxapp 1.0.0; wbx 1.0.0; Zoom 3.6.0)
> X-XSRF-TOKEN: ${COOKIE_XSRF-TOKEN}
> Content-Length: 621
> Host: rrsso.secure..com

> REsponse Body:
> [{"message": "Unauthorized Access"}]

> Response Header:
> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
> Date: Sun, 10 Jan 2021 21:12:55 GMT
> Server: Apache/2.4
> Set-Cookie: OAM_GITO=kGd/kyTPdkJwTv2i9WGraw==~sk4miutnl6uMea23C23aaELnRjNIe6GuJrzwgOeCmMWmJg3XEeS513k1yRTnvIzjqiYhuTZ8F/dZ/xA14Sgmm+TyoevctBX7jQDWIDlq9U6QKmMVXDPwEN2MNTjgWMNSPIaCpBgOX5LNupmZIXrygeONgoUQEgLZhsJkdXOJIVtshV8PLkNn+eGaYmtyVJAZCspGUocjSDXJzEh/wwRTZQUFruOMgSYqSo8QGIRfYOE=;Domain=.com; path=/
> Content-Length: 36
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
> Keep-Alive: timeout=8, max=1016
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 403 description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403):

> The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

> This status is similar to [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and **tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.**

So most probably the user which is successfully logged in doesn't have appropriate permissions to perform the action you're trying to implement. Make sure that you're using correct credentials and the user role is the one which can do the lookup of other roles.

If you're able to perform these steps successfully in the browser most probably JMeter sends something different, you need to compare the outgoing requests originated from JMeter and from the real browser, better using an external [sniffer tool](https://www.dnsstuff.com/packet-sniffers), the requests must be exactly the same (apart from dynamic parameters which needs to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/))

Comment: Hello Dmitri- Thank you for your input. There are no credential issue as I am able to perform the same actions through browser. I will look to see if there are any further correlation issues. Thanks!